# Fetch authorization token from headers

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, postman

I have been working on web services with wordpress and I hit Authorization token header from postman but enable to get that in php code. Here is my code.

```
$reuqest_token = getallheaders();
```

And here is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please anybody let me know if there is any another alternative.

Comment: What does `$reuqest_token = getallheaders();` output?

Comment: Please this http://pastebin.com/x3Nn8qjN

Comment: So, what's the problem to fetch the value from the array?

Comment: As you can see the array there is no value/key of Authorization. I am sending Authorization header from Postman but enable to get this header.

Comment: 1. it really does not matter if you use Postman, cUrl or browser.
2. have you tried PHP_AUTH_USER header? I'm not sure but it seems that PHP operates on auth info with parsing/naming headers [on its own](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)
Also it makes sense to dump all the headers maybe there is somrthing you need but with different name